# Set a shortcut key for Windows 8.1 Start screen

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-8.1, start-screen

I have currently set the behavior of <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> Windows button to go automatically to "Apps view" instead of the original Start screen.

[image]

But sometimes I want to go to the main **Start screen** (*not the **App view***) by pressing a single key or a shortcut. Is there there a way to do this so that my current setting of navigation will not change?

Comment: I didn't even know you could jump right to the App view, but I like it. So far, the only way I could find to open the Start Screen is Tab + Enter

Comment: You can toggle between the start screen and the all apps screen using `Control + Tab`. If you want a single key shortcut, you will need to resort to [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) though.